# Storing multiple PyTorch tensors of different shapes with names that are not known by advance

Tags: python, classes, properties, pytorch

I need to create a container for instances of torch.Tensor of different shapes, where I can call them by their name.

It is a use case for a dict except that:

I don't want to rely on the heavy syntax to make it clean. I was originally thinking about this but it is heavy...

```py
from typing import Dict
from torch import Tensor
from .constants import my_names

my_dict: Dict[str, Tensor] = {}
my_dict[my_names.FIELD_NAME] = Tensor([0,1,0])
assert my_dict[my_names.FIELD_NAME][0] == 0
```

Also, I wanted to do some shape-checking, which means I need to add another mechanism aside.

I came up with something. I don't know if it is clever or weird. I'm not used to ticking inside the definition of Python classes. Do you have simpler solutions that come to your mind?

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Optional
from torch import Tensor

class Tensors:

    def __init__(self):
        self._data: Dict[str,Tensor] = {}
        self._shapes: Dict[str,Tuple[int, ...]] = {}
        
    def __getattr__(self, key: str) -> Tensor:
        if key in ["_data","_shapes"]:
            return self.__dict__[key]
        return self._data[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key: str, value: Tensor) -> None:
        if key in ["_data","_shapes"]:
            self.__dict__[key] = value
        elif not value.shape == self._shapes[key]:
            raise ValueError(f"The shape of the tensor {key} must be {self._shapes[key]}, not {value.shape}")
        else:
            self._data[key] = value

    def __delattr__(self, key: str) -> None:
        if key in ["_data","_shapes"]:
            del self.__dict__[key]
        else:
            del self._data[key]

    def set_shape(self, key: str, value:Tuple[int,...]) -> None:
       self._shapes[key] = value

    ...

tensors = Tensors()
tensors.set_shape("result",(3,))
tensors.result = Tensor([0,1,0])
assert tensors.result[0] == 0
```